# What is the meaning of "Yes, Virginia, it had better be unsigned"?

Tags: string, linux-kernel, comments, cstring

In the linux source code version 3.18 (and previous), in the string.c file, in the function strncasecmp, the very first thing is:

```
/* Yes, Virginia, it had better be unsigned */
unsigned char c1, c2;
```

As can be seen here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/string.c

What is the meaning of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[string.c:strncasecmp()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/string.c#L37) calls `__tolower` from [include/linux/ctype.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/ctype.h#L38) which expects an `unsinged char`.

EDITed to add: In general you always want to pass `unsigned char` to ctype.h functions [because of C Standard §7.4, which says the behavior is undefined if the argument to ctype.h functions is not representable as `unsigned char` or `EOF`.](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/STR37-C.+Arguments+to+character-handling+functions+must+be+representable+as+an+unsigned+char) So that probably explains the ["Yes, Virginia"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes,_Virginia,_there_is_a_Santa_Claus) bit.

What is a bit more mysterious is that [include/linux/ctype.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/ctype.h#L38) actually appears idiot-proof in this respect, because it does its own [safety-minded cast](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/STR34-C.+Cast+characters+to+unsigned+char+before+converting+to+larger+integer+sizes) in `#define __ismask(x) (_ctype[(int)(unsigned char)(x)])`. I'm not sure when the "Yes, Virginia" comment was added relative to this other line, but with the current version of `include/linux/ctype.h` it appears that `string.c:strncasecmp()` would work fine even with `char` for `c1` and `c2`. I haven't really tried to change & test it that way though...

Also if you go back to [Linux 2.0.40's ctype.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/ctype.h?v=2.0.40), the safety-minded cast (`(int)(unsigned char)`) is not there anymore. There's no "Virginia" comment either in [2.0.40's string.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/string.c?v=2.0.40), but there's not even a `strncasecmp` in it. It looks like both changes were made somewhere in between Linux 2.0 and 2.2, but I can't tell you more right now which came first, etc.

Comment: If you search for "virginia" in the linux tree, there are more instances of "yes, Virginia, something something". It's probably a reference to some old nerdy thing (_nerdy_ not in any way in a bad sense).

Comment: The Wikipedia article on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes,_Virginia,_there_is_a_Santa_Claus (which I linked in my answer) does mention this "nerdy" aspect. One referece it cites as illustration of the social phenomenon (meme) is http://vrt-blog.snort.org/2010/07/yes-virginia-there-is-cyberwar.html It's surely older though.

Comment: I think it refers to the C standard that defines three different types: `char`, `unsigned char`, and `signed char`. And they are slightly different on some architectures and / or compilers.